# Random ">" sign appearing above a table in HTML

Tags: html, css, random, character

I wouldn't say I'm new to webdev (and coding in general), but I'm certainly not professional. I've been making a website for my flight school and on one of my pages, I've run into a problem: A random ">" appears above a table whenever the `<table>` tag is included. I've been looking on Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, and Google in general for about three hours now, and I've come up with nothing. This only happens on one page, and only with this table. Take out just the "" and it goes away; add it back in and it appears again. It will even show up in Chrome's Inspect Element (but not in the source code, obviously). I've rewritten this page so many times that I felt this was the last option. I'll attach the HTML source and the CSS so that you guys can take a look... Any help at all is much appreciated!!!

```
><!doctype html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/mainTemplate.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>Rochester Air Center</title>
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/photos/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="photos/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerWrapper">
        <div id="banner">
            <img src="photos/banner.png" width="796px" height="44px"></img>
        </div>
        <div id="timeDiv">
                <a href="conditions.html" id="time">Greenwich Mean Time:&nbsp;<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4d9h5z3/n136/fn2/fs16/fcfff/tct/pc000/ftb/tt0/th1/tb1" frameborder="0" width="360" height="30" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></a>
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div id="navWrapper">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
             <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="parts.html">Parts and Licenses</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="part61.html">Part 61</a></li>
                <li><a href="part141.html">Part 141</a></li> 
                <li><a style="cursor : pointer">Licenses</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="privateLicense.html">Private Pilots License</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ifr.html">Instrument Flight Rating (IFR)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cpl.html">Commercial Pilots License (CPL)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cfi.html">Certified Flight Instructor (CFI)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="pilotShopAndFacility">Pilot Shop and Facility</a></li>
            <li><!--<a href="fleet.html">Fleet</a>--><a href="fleet-place-holder.html">Fleet</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><!--<a href="150.html">Cessna 150</a>--><a href="plane-place-holder.html">Cessna 150</a></li>        
                    <li><!--<a href="152.html">Cessna 152</a>--><a href="plane-place-holder.html">Cessna 152</a></li>
                    <li><!--<a href="172.html">Cessna 172</a>--><a href="plane-place-holder.html">Cessna 172</a></li>
                    <li><!--<a href="172sp.html">Cessna 172SP</a>--><a href="plane-place-holder.html">Cessna 172SP</a></li>
                    <li><!--<a href="182.html">Cessna 182</a>--><a href="plane-place-holder.html">Cessna 182</a></li>
                    <li><!--<a href="citabria.html">Citabria</a>--><a href="plane-place-holder.html">Citabria</a></li>
                    <li><!--<a href="pa28.html">Piper 28</a>--><a href="plane-place-holder.html">Piper 28</a></li>
                    <li><!--<a href="seneca.html">Piper Seneca</a>--><a href="plane-place-holder.html">Piper Seneca</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photos/redbird.pdf" target="_blank">Flight Simulator - Redbird</a></li>        
                </ul>    
            </li>
            <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
            <li><a href="instructors.html">Instructors</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="alecMetildi.html">Alec Metildi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="christopherCaschette.html">Christopher Caschette</a></li>
                    <li><a href="edVorbach.html">Ed Vorbach</a></li>
                    <li><a href="josephSongin.html">Joseph Songin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shawnFlickner.html">Shawn Flickner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="toddCameron.html">Todd Cameron</a></li>
                    <li><a href="royCzernikoski.html">Roy Czernikoski</a></li>
                    <li><a href="johnDougherty.html">John Dougherty</a></li>
                    <li><a href="danKindred.html">Dan Kindred</a></li>
                    <li><a href="robertMcNamara.html">Robert McNamara</a></li>
                    <li><a href="geraldFrumusa.html">Gerald Frumusa</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://login.flightschedulepro.com/login.aspx?Id=45947&Code=45947&noauth=true" id="schedule" target="_blank">Online Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>      
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="content">
                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="content" -->
                <table width="90%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="rates" align="center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="background-color : yellow; color : black">
                            <td>
                                <h3 class="ratesTable">Model</h3>
                          </td>
                         <td>
                                <h3 class="ratesTable">Callsign</h3>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <h3 class="ratesTable">Equipment</h3>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <h3 class="ratesTable">Aircraft Price per Hour</h3>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <h3 class="ratesTable">Instructor Price per Hour</h3>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <h3 class="ratesTable">Total Price per Hour</h3>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                        <td>
                            Cessna 150
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            N225RA
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            VFR; VOR
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $90.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $55.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $145.00
                        </td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                        <td>
                            Cessna 152
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            N714WS
                     </td>
                        <td>
                            VFR; VOR
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $95.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $55.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $150.00
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                        <td>
                            Cessna 172M
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            N1126U
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            IFR; Dual VOR
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $125.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $55.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $180.00
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                        <td>
                            Cessna 172M
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            N998RA
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            IFR; Dual VOR; Garmin 400 GPS
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $125.00
                     </td>
                        <td>
                            $55.00
                        </td>
                     <td>
                            $180.00
                        </td>
                    </tr>>
                    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                        <td>
                            Cessna 172M
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            N5270H
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            IFR; Dual VOR
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $125.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $55.00
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            $180.00
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                        <td>
                            Cessna 172SP
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            N225RA
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            IFR; Dual VOR; GPS; Autopilot
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $140.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $55.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $195.00
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                        <td>
                            Cessna 182
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            N992RA
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            IFR; Dual VOR; GPS
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $145.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $55.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $200.00
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                    <td>
                            Citabria
                     </td>
                        <td>
                            N197
                      </td>
                       <td>
                            VFR
                     </td>
                        <td>
                            $130.00
                       </td>
                       <td>
                            $55.00
                       </td>
                        <td>
                            $185.00
                       </td>
                 </tr>
        <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
            <td>
                Piper 28-200R
            </td>
            <td>
                N827RA
            </td>
            <td>
                IFR; VOR; GPS; Complex (Retractable Gear, Flaps, Constant Speed Propeller)
            </td>
            <td>
                $140.00
            </td>
            <td>
                $55.00
            </td>
            <td>
                $195.00
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
            <td>
                Piper Seneca II
            </td>
            <td>
                N78SF
            </td>
            <td>
                IFR; GPS; VOR
            </td>
            <td>
                $275.00
            </td>
            <td>
                $60.00
            </td>
            <td>
                $335.00
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
            <td>
                Full Motion Flight Simulator
            </td>
            <td>
                Redbird
            </td>
            <td>
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                $65.00
            </td>
            <td>
                $55.00
            </td>
            <td>
                $120.00
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
            <td>
                Ground Instruction
            </td>
            <td>
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                -
            </td>
            <td>
                $55.00
            </td>
            <td>
                $55.00
            </td>
        </tr>      
    </tbody>
  </table>  
  <br />
  <br />
      </div>
    </div>  
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
        <a href="faq.html" class="footer">Frequently Asked Questions</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="map.html" class="footer">Site Map</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="aboutUs.html" class="footer">About Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="contact.html" class="footer">Contact Us</a>
    </div>      
</body>
```

And here's my (related) CSS:

> body { background-color : #000000; background-image : url('photos/background.jpg'); background-repeat : no-repeat; font-size: 13pt; background-attachment : fixed; color : #000000; font-family : arial }

```
table { font-size : 13pt; color : #000000; font-family : arial; text-align : center }
    table.rates { font-family : times }
    table.holder { background-color : #FFFFFF; color : #000000; text-align : center }
tr { font-size : 13pt; color : #000000; font-family : times; text-align : center }
td { font-size : 13pt; color : #000000; font-family : times; text-align : center }
```

I apologize for all of the overriding and such, I was having some problems, and once it worked, I left it... and yes, I am using Dreamweaver, and yes, I know it's not great for webdev anymore. Anyway... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look inside your table for a stray `>` that's not inside a table sub element. Anything like that will appear right before the table when rendered.

Comment: I also noticed an extra `>` before the `<doctype>` declaration. Was just just an error while writing the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra `>` at the end of this row:

```html
<tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
  <td>
    Cessna 172M
  </td>
  <td>
    N998RA
  </td>
  <td>
    IFR; Dual VOR; Garmin 400 GPS
  </td>
  <td>
    $125.00
  </td>
  <td>
    $55.00
  </td>
  <td>
    $180.00
  </td>
</tr>><!-- here it is -->
```

Comment: Wow, there goes about five hours of my life... I can't thank you guys enough, that was driving me crazy! I was always looking at only the top little bit. I guess that shows you why I'm not great at this yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have the following in your markup which is resulting in an extra >

```
</tr>>
```

I found it right away using ctrl-f >>. Another good idea is to use an html validator to check for these kinds of errors. For example, http://validator.w3.org/. A lot of code editors will check for validity too, although I'm not sure if Dream Weaver is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

it has been fixed

replace your table content with the following (copy and paste)

```
<table width="90%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="rates" align="center">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="background-color : yellow; color : black">
                        <td>
                            <h3 class="ratesTable">Model</h3>
                      </td>
                     <td>
                            <h3 class="ratesTable">Callsign</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <h3 class="ratesTable">Equipment</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <h3 class="ratesTable">Aircraft Price per Hour</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <h3 class="ratesTable">Instructor Price per Hour</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <h3 class="ratesTable">Total Price per Hour</h3>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                    <td>
                        Cessna 150
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        N225RA
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        VFR; VOR
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $90.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $55.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $145.00
                    </td>    
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                    <td>
                        Cessna 152
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        N714WS
                 </td>
                    <td>
                        VFR; VOR
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $95.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $55.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $150.00
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                    <td>
                        Cessna 172M
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        N1126U
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        IFR; Dual VOR
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $125.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $55.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $180.00
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                    <td>
                        Cessna 172M
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        N998RA
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        IFR; Dual VOR; Garmin 400 GPS
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $125.00
                 </td>
                    <td>
                        $55.00
                    </td>
                 <td>
                        $180.00
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                    <td>
                        Cessna 172M
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        N5270H
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        IFR; Dual VOR
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $125.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $55.00
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        $180.00
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                    <td>
                        Cessna 172SP
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        N225RA
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        IFR; Dual VOR; GPS; Autopilot
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $140.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $55.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $195.00
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                    <td>
                        Cessna 182
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        N992RA
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        IFR; Dual VOR; GPS
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $145.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $55.00
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $200.00
                    </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
                <td>
                        Citabria
                 </td>
                    <td>
                        N197
                  </td>
                   <td>
                        VFR
                 </td>
                    <td>
                        $130.00
                   </td>
                   <td>
                        $55.00
                   </td>
                    <td>
                        $185.00
                   </td>
             </tr>
    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
        <td>
            Piper 28-200R
        </td>
        <td>
            N827RA
        </td>
        <td>
            IFR; VOR; GPS; Complex (Retractable Gear, Flaps, Constant Speed Propeller)
        </td>
        <td>
            $140.00
        </td>
        <td>
            $55.00
        </td>
        <td>
            $195.00
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
        <td>
            Piper Seneca II
        </td>
        <td>
            N78SF
        </td>
        <td>
            IFR; GPS; VOR
        </td>
        <td>
            $275.00
        </td>
        <td>
            $60.00
        </td>
        <td>
            $335.00
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
        <td>
            Full Motion Flight Simulator
        </td>
        <td>
            Redbird
        </td>
        <td>
            -
        </td>
        <td>
            $65.00
        </td>
        <td>
            $55.00
        </td>
        <td>
            $120.00
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color : white; color : black; font-family : times">
        <td>
            Ground Instruction
        </td>
        <td>
            -
        </td>
        <td>
            -
        </td>
        <td>
            -
        </td>
        <td>
            $55.00
        </td>
        <td>
            $55.00
        </td>
    </tr>      
</tbody>
</table>
```